# Python x Tweepy: how to pull tweets from all users contained within a list

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm very, very new to Python as disclosure.

I have successfully pulled all users who are members of a list on Twitter. I have also pulled all tweets of a user, based on screen name - both components contained below. How do I combine these, and pull *all tweets* of *all users* who are members of a list please? Is this even possible? Everything below:

```
#GOAL: pull all tweets from all users who are memberis of a list.

#imports necessary methods from Twitter library
import json
import tweepy
import time
import csv
import sys

#authorises twitter
CONSUMER_KEY = 'SECRET'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'SECRET'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'SECRET'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'SECRET'

#authorisations
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#returns members of a list & some details on them 
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, slug="uk-mps-labour", owner_screen_name="tweetminster", include_entities=True).items():
    print(f"{user.id}\t{user.screen_name}\t{user.name}\t{user.description}\t{user.location}\t{user.followers_count}\t{user.friends_count}\t{user.verified}")

#creates a loop to iterate through the list of user ids 

#returns all tweets of a user 
counter = 0 #establishes a counter to number tweets output
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name="frogface", tweet_mode="extended").items():
     counter = counter + 1
     print(f"{counter}\t{status.user.id}\t{status.user.screen_name}\t{status.created_at}\t{status.full_text}")
```

Comment: You need to use [tweepy stream](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html#) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are iterating through users of the list instead of printing the user details, add the screen_name to a list.

next iterate through the screen_names list and then get the users tweets. The code will look something like this:

```
 screen_names = []

#returns members of a list & some details on them 
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, slug="uk-mps-labour", owner_screen_name="tweetminster", include_entities=True).items():
    screen_names.append(f"{user.screen_name}")

for i in screen_names:
    #returns all tweets of a user 
    counter = 0 #establishes a counter to number tweets output
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=i, tweet_mode="extended").items():
         counter = counter + 1
         print(f"{counter}\t{status.user.id}\t{status.user.screen_name}\t{status.created_at}\t{status.full_text}")
```

Comment: The answer is python way of doing it, but as @prateek has mentioned you can check tweepy stream functionality which seems like the right way to do it. Also please confirm the solution if it worked .